# Unit test(chromeheadless) with Angular 15 failing on CI/CD (using Docker) saying Operation not permitted

Tags: angular, angular15

Unit test(chromeheadless) with Angular 15 failing on CI/CD saying below error -
ChromeHeadless stderr: Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted

Below is the detailed error log -

Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted

[2023-04-13T06:56:27.964Z]  | [0413/065627.764156:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)

[2023-04-13T06:56:27.964Z]   | [0413/065627.764229:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

[2023-04-13T06:56:27.964Z]   | [0413/065627.768643:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir /tmp/Crashpad/attachments/d18fc84e-fc11-4821-b4df-b74d70899830: No such file or directory (2)

[2023-04-13T06:56:27.964Z]   |

[2023-04-13T06:56:27.964Z]   | 13 04 2023 06:56:27.854:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stdout:

[2023-04-13T06:56:27.964Z]  | 13 04 2023 06:56:27.854:ERROR [launcher]: ChromeHeadless stderr: [0413/065627.739538:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(152)] open /tmp/Crashpad/pending/94771f51-6320-4e84-ad8b-3a479c1adac9.lock: File exists (17)

[2023-04-13T06:56:27.964Z]   | Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Operation not permitted

[2023-04-13T06:56:27.964Z]   | [0413/065627.764156:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq: No such file or directory (2)

[2023-04-13T06:56:27.964Z]  | [0413/065627.764229:ERROR:file_io_posix.cc(144)] open /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_max_freq: No such file or directory (2)

[2023-04-13T06:56:27.964Z] | [0413/065627.768643:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir /tmp/Crashpad/attachments/d18fc84e-fc11-4821-b4df-b74d70899830: No such file or directory (2)...